# How to disable lane changes in SuMO?

Tags: veins, sumo, plexe-veins, plexe

I am using a [TraCI call](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/w/index.php?title=TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State&oldid=10798#lane_change_mode_.280xb6.29) to set the lane change mode of a vehicle to `0`  to disable all lane changing:

`TraCICommandInterface::setLaneChangeMode(0b000000000000);`

However, the vehicle still does a lane change afterwards. I also tried 256 (i.e. `0b000100000000` and 512 (i.e. `0b001000000000`) as indicated in the [wiki](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/w/index.php?title=TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State&oldid=10798#lane_change_mode_.280xb6.29) or in [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/sumo/mailman/message/32151580/).

It seems that the executed lane change action was queued earlier (i.e. before the TraCI call), because the vehicle is flashing its turn light, and could not be executed due to a blocked lane. After the target lane is free, the vehicle executes the lane change, even though I set the lane change mode to `0`.

- Is there a way to abort already queued lane changes?
- Or is this a bug in SuMO?
- Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it works by setting setLaneChangeMode(0b000000000000)
for example
`traci.vehicle.setLaneChangeMode("rear", 0b001000000000)`

Answer (score 0):

i have disabled lane change mode by this code and it worked but after i have specified the location where i want lane change mode to be 0.

```
traciVehicle->setLaneChangeMode(0b001000000000);
```

Comment: I am not sure, whether I got your point or, more precisely, the difference to the stuff I tried already. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In my case i wanted to stop lane change mode when vehicle become near to junction(about 15 to 25 m) so i have checked the distance between vehicle and junction then above code has been activated. It worked and i didn't see any lane change in that area

Comment: I see. Thanks. I will rethink my scenario.

Comment: hope it helped you