# Control lane change decision in SUMO

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using VEINS 4.4 , OMNET 5.0 and SUMO 0.25 in my project. i want to stop vehicles from changing their lanes when they become near to the intersection .

i have searched in google but i didn't get an answer

how to do it, please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875773/how-to-disable-lane-changes-in-sumo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a Traci command that control the changing lane in Veins. I came across this implementation in [burtonwilliamt github rep](https://github.com/burtonwilliamt/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc):

```
void TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::setLaneChangeMode(int32_t bitset) {
    uint8_t variableId = VAR_LANECHANGE_MODE;
    uint8_t variableType = TYPE_INTEGER;
    TraCIBuffer buf = traci->connection.query(CMD_SET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << variableId << nodeId << variableType << bitset);
    ASSERT(buf.eof());
}
```

I have not tested it thou.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you mean that i need to add this code in my veins files because i didn't find this code in my TraCICommandInterface.cc

Comment: Yes, you need to add it in the main veins TraCICommandInterface class